# Rejecting new http requests when memory usage is high in GoLang

Tags: go, kubernetes, server, rate-limiting

I have a simple http server written in Go that accepts big chunks of data (up to 5MB per single request in some cases, but can be even tens of KB, depends on the usage pattern). Then server asynchronously processes received data by adding it to the buffer from which one of the workers (goroutines) pick ups a task. This server is running as a container in kubernetes and has a memory limit set. Also unfortunately I'm not allowed to use HPA as only one pod is allowed per client.

Problem occurs when, someone tries to send a lot of big chunks of data to my server, due to memory limit kubelet kills my container and as a result all data stored in the buffer is lost.

I have tried next ways to mitigate a problem:

1. Remove memory limit in pod specs. Unfortunately my server is running in multitenant environment and I'm forced to set memory limit.
2. Limited a number of requests processed in flight by adding a buffered channel and timeout when request can't be added to it in 10 seconds. This has partially mitigated a problem. But first it's quite tricky to find a good balance between a buffer size and timeout, second if client has a lot of small requests server is dropping part of them even if it has a lot of free memory.

I have found that I get current memory usage of my binary by calling [runtime.GetMemStats](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats). So my next idea is to drop requests if for example memory goes above some threshold (80%). Is it the only solution to resolve a problem?

Comment: Do you have to read everything? Can you change your processing to stream the input so you don't have to store the whole request in memory?

Comment: The problem that I need to answer to client as soon as it possible if request is accepted or not. So first we are performing fast check of it (and if something is not right report 4xx) and then put the data into the buffer and return 200 to the client. After that request is processed (it might take near half a minute to process it). So we need to read the whole request into memory.

Comment: In that case, I guess the best you can do is to keep the size of active requests and deny new ones after a certain threshold.

Comment: Pods can have writable disk space, and that's usually cheaper than memory.  Have you considered saving the data to disk as it comes in?  Then send the name of the file to the goroutine instead of the entire content ?  At some point you outgrow the limitations of your hosting choice.  ''

Comment: You can also use a semaphore to keep track of active requests vs available workers, which seems like an improvement over the "write to channel within 10 seconds or timeout" as you can send the response to the client immediately.  A weighted semaphore would let you account for the size of the requests in flight and not just their quantity, which also helps with your small requests vs big requests.   https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore